# Can I remove/add jars in Jetty classpath without restarting it?

Tags: java, jetty

my Jetty is started by `java -jar starter.jar -cp lib`, I put all jars required by my applications in `lib`, at some point later, I may upgrade my war file along with some new jar files, will I have to restart Jetty to make it effective?

please help.

Comment: WAR files are part of the Servlet Spec isolated classloaders, all of the content for the WAR file can be replaced with a Hot Deploy.  Consider not using `${jetty.base}/lib/` if you can.  Your life will be so much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The container will still have the old list of jar files and unless you restart it will not come into effect.

Comment: what will happen if the server hot-deploy my war file, but retains old jar files?

Comment: @JerryChin If the new war contains classes that use the new jars, they will throw `ClassNotFoundException` when executed.

Comment: @JerryChin Still unless you restart the new jars will not be available within the server container unless you restart.